# Translate Java Class Strings on Android

Tags: java, android

I want to translate these Strings of my Java Class:

```
String s = getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_date, shipping_date.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s));
String t = getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_time, shipping_time.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(t));
String u = getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_address_c, shipping_address_address.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(u));
String v = getResources().getString(R.string.transport_description_c, description.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(v));
String w = getResources().getString(R.string.weight, weight.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(w));
String x = getResources().getString(R.string.destination_date, shipping_date.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(x));
String z = getResources().getString(R.string.destination_address, shipping_date.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(z));
```

my string.xml file is this:

```
<string name="shipping_date">"&lt;b>1it: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
<string name="shipping_time">"&lt;b>2it: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
<string name="shipping_address_c">"&lt;b>3it: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
<string name="transport_description_c">"&lt;b>4it: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
<string name="weight">"&lt;b>5it: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
<string name="destination_date">"&lt;b>6it: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
<string name="destination_address">"&lt;b>7it: &lt;/b>  %1$s"</string>
```

But I get only one of them on my app:

[image: Screenshot]

Could someone please help me?

Comment: Why is this tagged as PHP? I also don't see Java or Android tags

Comment: @mquinn ...or CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You're overwriting the last text set by repeatedly calling `loaddate.setText()`. Instead concat them into one string and call `loaddate.setText()` once like this:

```
String s = getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_date, shipping_date.toString());
String t = getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_time, shipping_time.toString());
String u = getResources().getString(R.string.shipping_address_c, shipping_address_address.toString());
String v = getResources().getString(R.string.transport_description_c, description.toString());
String w = getResources().getString(R.string.weight, weight.toString());
String x = getResources().getString(R.string.destination_date, shipping_date.toString());
String z = getResources().getString(R.string.destination_address, shipping_date.toString());
loaddate.setText(Html.fromHtml(s + t + u + v + w + x + z));
```

Comment: Hi @ahasbini,thank you for your answer. I put your code and run emulator but I got last code line red underlined, Error:(103, 43) error: bad operand types for binary operator '+'first type:  Spannedsecond type: Spanned

Comment: Ahh, have never used `Html.fromHtml()` from before. Check updated answer please.